# Where is the place to run HTTP requests?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I've been mingling in the world of API's and GET requests, but I'm not sure how to make usual ones. I know the basic python and javascript ones, but I want to know how to make a straight-up one. The usual:
`GET 'https://api.roblox.com'`
or something like that.
Please help!

Comment: I don't really understand your question, are you just trying to send a `GET` request to  `https://api.roblox.com`?

Comment: I mean where do I run the command
`GET 'https://api.roblox.com'`

Comment: What do you mean by "where"? are you referring to where to run python code in general?

Comment: Like what language? This has nothing to do with python.

Comment: Be more specific when you are posting a question so that others can help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a `GET` [request](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request):

```py
import requests  # pip install requests

r = requests.get('https://api.roblox.com')
print(r.status_code, r.text)
```

Comment: GET is not a command or program. If you want to make a raw HTTP request, use netcat for example.

Comment: And why did you add python-requests tag to your question?

Comment: It was a simple accident, okay?

Comment: This would be acceptable with python in most cases, so I'll accept it.